# Linking JavaFX 8 TableView selections

Tags: java, javafx

I've written the following code that links the selection between two tableviews.  The issue that I'm facing is that the link is only done on the index of the row rather than matching the cell content.

Ideally, if 'Paper' is selected in either table I would like all rows in both tables with the `<name>` equal to Paper highlighted too.

Is there any simple & efficient method of achieving this?

This is the test code I've written so far:

```
public class TableSelection extends Application {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ObservableList<Item> data1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Item> data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    String[] names = new String[]{"Wood", "Paper", "Scissors"};

    for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        Item j = new Item();
        j.setName(names[(int)(Math.random() * names.length)]);
        j.setNn((int)(Math.random() * 100));

        if (i<5) data1.add(j);
        else data2.add(j);
    }

    TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    TableColumn<Item, Integer> nnCol = new TableColumn<>("nn");
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("Name"));
    nnCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, Integer>("nn"));

    TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol2 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    TableColumn<Item, Integer> nnCol2 = new TableColumn<>("nn");
    nameCol2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("Name"));
    nnCol2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, Integer>("nn"));

    TableView<Item> table1 = new TableView<>();
    table1.itemsProperty().setValue(data1);     
    table1.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, nnCol);

    TableView<Item> table2 = new TableView<>();
    table2.itemsProperty().setValue(data2);     
    table2.getColumns().addAll(nameCol2, nnCol2);

    table1.setSelectionModel(table2.getSelectionModel());   
    table1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    VBox myPane = new VBox();
    myPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    myPane.setPadding(new Insets(12));
    myPane.setSpacing(12);
    myPane.setMaxHeight(500);
    myPane.getChildren().addAll(table1, table2);

    Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);

    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. But be aware that there may be situations with synchronization issues because of the changing of the selection model while you select cells (concurrency).

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableSelection extends Application {

    TableView<Item> table1 = new TableView<>();
    TableView<Item> table2 = new TableView<>();

    boolean adapting = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Item> data1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Item> data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        String[] names = new String[] { "Wood", "Paper", "Scissors" };

        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
            Item j = new Item();
            j.setName(names[(int) (Math.random() * names.length)]);
            j.setNn((int) (Math.random() * 100));

            if (i < 5)
                data1.add(j);
            else
                data2.add(j);
        }

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Item, Integer> nnCol = new TableColumn<>("nn");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("Name"));
        nnCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, Integer>("nn"));

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol2 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Item, Integer> nnCol2 = new TableColumn<>("nn");
        nameCol2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("Name"));
        nnCol2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, Integer>("nn"));

        table1.itemsProperty().setValue(data1);
        table1.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, nnCol);

        table2.itemsProperty().setValue(data2);
        table2.getColumns().addAll(nameCol2, nnCol2);

        // table1.setSelectionModel(table2.getSelectionModel());
        table1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        table2.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        table2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Item>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (adapting)
                return;

            try {

                adapting = true;

                selectCurrent(table2);
                selectOthers(table2, table1);

            } finally {
                adapting = false;
            }

        });

        table1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Item>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if (adapting)
                return;

            try {

                adapting = true;

                selectCurrent(table1);
                selectOthers(table1, table2);

            } finally {
                adapting = false;
            }

        });

        VBox myPane = new VBox();
        myPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        myPane.setPadding(new Insets(12));
        myPane.setSpacing(12);
        myPane.setMaxHeight(500);
        myPane.getChildren().addAll(table1, table2);

        Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void selectCurrent(TableView<Item> currentTableView) {

        Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

        for (Item item : currentTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            names.add(item.getName());
        }

        for (String name : names) {

            for (Item item : currentTableView.getItems()) {
                if (name.equals(item.getName())) {
                    currentTableView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    private void selectOthers(TableView<Item> sourceTableView, TableView<Item> targetTableView) {

        Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

        for (Item item : sourceTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            names.add(item.getName());
        }

        targetTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

        for (String name : names) {

            for (Item item : targetTableView.getItems()) {
                if (name.equals(item.getName())) {
                    targetTableView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public class Item {
        String name;
        int Nn;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getNn() {
            return Nn;
        }

        public void setNn(int nn) {
            Nn = nn;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You could unify the creation of the name collection. And you should use an AtomicBoolean or other synchronization methods for the guard clause. I leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't expecting such a quick turnaround on my question.

Comment: Although I haven't tested your code yet I can see it wasn't a simple 'one-liner'.  You've also confirmed my thoughts about having a unique list to feed the TableViews as I wasn't sure if (or how) JavaFX would handle this.  I'll try the code tonight -  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Following your advice I tried to unify the name selection.  Since I was getting lost in my own code I changed it to a single selection rather than multiple.  I also experimented with the way the rows were highlighted as I thought maybe using the css highlighting might be more efficient targetTableView.getSelectionModel().select(item).

Both the name selection and the highlighting work but the two are disconnected. I know the highlighting works as I've initialised a value, but it doesn't get updated when I select a new value.

Is there something else I need to do in the cellfactory?

Thanks for any advice!

Here's the full code:

```
package standAloneTest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableSelection extends Application {

    protected String selectedName ="Paper";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Item> data1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Item> data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        String[] names = new String[] { "Wood", "Paper", "Scissors" };

        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
            Item j = new Item();
            j.setName(names[(int) (Math.random() * names.length)]);
            j.setNn((int) (Math.random() * 100));

            if (i < 5)
                data1.add(j);
            else
                data2.add(j);
        }

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Item, Integer> nnCol = new TableColumn<>("nn");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("Name"));
        nnCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, Integer>("nn"));
        //nameCol.setCellFactory();

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol2 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Item, Integer> nnCol2 = new TableColumn<>("nn");
        nameCol2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("Name"));

        nameCol2.setCellFactory(column -> {
          return new TableCell<Item, String>() {
              protected void updateItem(String n, boolean empty){
                  super.updateItem(n, empty);
                  System.out.println("string : " + n);
                  if (n == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setStyle("");
                  } else {
                      setText(n);

                      // Style if selected value
                      if (n.equals(selectedName) ){
                          setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                      }
                  }
             }    
          };
        });

        nnCol2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, Integer>("nn"));


        TableView<Item> table1 = new TableView<>();
        table1.itemsProperty().setValue(data1);
        table1.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, nnCol);

        TableView<Item> table2 = new TableView<>();
        table2.itemsProperty().setValue(data2);
        table2.getColumns().addAll(nameCol2, nnCol2);

        // table1.setSelectionModel(table2.getSelectionModel());
        table1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Item>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Item> observable, Item oldValue, Item newValue) {
                selectedName = newValue.getName().toString();
                System.out.println(selectedName);
            }
        });

        table2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Item>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Item> observable, Item oldValue, Item newValue) {
                selectedName = newValue.getName().toString();
                System.out.println(selectedName);
            }
        });



        VBox myPane = new VBox();
        myPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        myPane.setPadding(new Insets(12));
        myPane.setSpacing(12);
        myPane.setMaxHeight(500);
        myPane.getChildren().addAll(table1, table2);

        Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```